# How to get bazel's rules_docker to use the repository cache

Tags: docker, caching, bazel

<sub>(This is an answer-your-own-question question: the answer is trivial but I did not find it easily: this is an attempt at fixing this)</sub>

If you depend on docker containers via `container_pull` with Bazel and `rules_docker`, it seems that you'll need to redownload the docker images relatively frequently. This becomes particularly problematic for images that are several hundreds of Mb's.

It looks like `rules_docker` ignores the `--repository_cache` configuration flag.

See below for the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rules_docker` will only cache to the path specified by `DOCKER_REPO_CACHE`, if it is set.

See [this documentation page](https://docs.aspect.build/bazelbuild/rules_docker/454981e65fa100d37b19210ee85fedb2f7af9626/docs/container.html#container_pull) for `container_pull` regarding the caveats:

> NOTE: Set DOCKER_REPO_CACHE env variable to make the container puller cache downloaded layers at the directory specified as a value to this env variable. The caching feature hasn't been thoroughly tested and may be thread unsafe. If you notice flakiness after enabling it, see the warning below on how to workaround it.
>
> NOTE: container_pull is suspected to have thread safety issues. To ensure multiple container_pull(s) don't execute concurrently, please use the bazel startup flag --loading_phase_threads=1 in your bazel invocation (typically by adding startup --loading_phase_threads=1 as a line in your .bazelrc)